# SwiftUI Text doesn't fit full width while having multiple lines

Tags: swiftui

there's an issue with SwiftUI's `Text` view while having multiple lines. So just look:

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Some word Some word Some word Some word")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .border(.red)
        .padding(16)
}
```

[image]

However adding **one** word changing the wrapping:

[image]

As result the view doesn't look as expected, for bigger fonts the difference become more visible:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Environment**: iOS 15.2, Xcode 13 / Xcode 14b Preview and Simulator

Is there a reliable solution to wrap strings similarly as `UILabel` do without using `UIViewRepresentable`?

**PS:** already tried different combinations with `.fixedSize()` + `.frame(idealWidth:)` and no luck

Comment: @Asperi yes but I would say it's rather a workaround

Comment: Well, using UILabel wrapped into UIViewRepresentable != Native swift UI view, at least from the perspective of using Environment modifiers (for foregroundColor there's no key) so wrapping such LabelView into Stack and then trying to apply text color won't work. Second moment is about using async, which behaves differently then native layout. With that using snapshots under Tests fails autolayout as result no text is displayed. Even if use UILabel need to get more reliable layouting mechanism then accepted answer

Comment: To me, this seems like a SwiftUI issue. I've filed a rdar: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5496539682177024

Answer (score 11):

Apple is following typography rules. One of those rules is to avoid having a single word on the last line of a paragraph. This **runt**, as it is called, is believed to break a reader's focus due to all the white space. However, if the last word and any trailing punctuation is greater than 10 characters this rule does not apply.

No option exists to turn this rule off directly to my knowledge. But a workaround is to use trailing spaces at the end of the text where this could occur. Use enough trailing spaces to make the last line have greater than 10 characters.

Using your example, adding 7 trailing spaces works. "Some" plus 7 spaces being 11 characters:

```
Text("Some word Some word Some word Some word Some       ")
```

[image]

In this example, 8 trailing spaces works. "the" plus 8 spaces provides 11 characters so the rule does not apply and the line breaks where desired:

```
 Text("Some word to demonstrate the        ")
```

[image]

And with the trailing spaces, the layout should look ok with larger devices and when orientation changes occur. Fortunately the trailing spaces are truncated and will not create a new line on their own.

```
extension String {
    var padded: String { self + "           " }
}
```

Usage:

```
Text("Some word to demonstrate the".padded)
```

Side note: UILabel(versions 13.0, 16.1) also appears to use these typography rules by default. But a UILabel can turn off this typography rule with the line break strategy setting:

```
label.lineBreakStrategy = NSParagraphStyle.LineBreakStrategy()
```

Or like this:

```
label.lineBreakStrategy = []
```

But it doesn't appear to be available in SwiftUI yet.